# Move application from homestead to docker

Tags: laravel, docker, homestead

My application consists of three domains:

- example.com
- admin.example.com
- partner.example.com

All of these domains are handled by the same Laravel app. Each domain has its own controllers and view. Models and other core functionalities are shared between all three domains.

Currently my local dev-environment is build with Homestead (based on Vagrant), where each local domain (`example.test`, `admin.example.test` and `partner.example.test`) points to the same directory (e.g. `/home/vagrant/app/public`).

Because of deployment problems regarding different versions of OS, NPM, PHP, etc. I want to move to docker. I've read a lot of articles about multiple domains or apps with docker. Best practice seems to be to set up an Nginx reverse proxy which redirects all incoming requests to the desired app. Unfortunately, I haven't found examples for my case where all domains point to the same application.

If possible I would avoid having the same repository cloned three times for each docker container running one specific part of the app.

So what would be the best approach to set up a docker environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple gist for you to look at of how I would do it
https://gist.github.com/karlisabele/f7d91594c004e227e504473ce2c60508

The nginx config file is based on Laravel documetation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#nginx) and of course in production you would also want to handle SSL and map port 443 as well, but this should serve as POC for you.

Notice that in the nginx configuration I use the php-fpm service name to pass the request to php-fpm container. In docker the service names can be used as host names for corresponding service so the line `fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;` means that you are passing the request to php-fpm containers port 9000 (default port for the fpm image to listen to)

Basically what you want to do is simply define in the nginx that all 3 of your subdomains are handled by the same server configuration. Then nginx simply passes the request to php-fpm to actually process it.

To test, you can just copy the two files from gist in your project directory, replace YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER in docker-compose.yml file with the actual location of your project (can be simply .:/var/www/html if you place the docker-compose.yml in the root of your project) then run `docker-compose up -d`. Add the domains to your hosts file (/etc/hosts un linux/mac) and you should be able to visit example.test and see your site.

Note: Depending on where your database is located, you might need to change the host for it if it's localhost at the moment, because it will try to connect to a mysql server from php-fpm container, which of course does not have it's own mysql-server running.

Comment: Seems the gist is no longer available.

Comment: @jdenoc Thank you for reminding me. Fixed it!